How to load a StyledLayer with raster data from PostGIS
I have created a table in PostGIS with raster data. I can't find any information about how I can create a StyledLayer with that rasterdata?
I've tried this... but its not the correct way:
 StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();
 featureSource=dataStore.getFeatureSource("raster_table_name");
 RasterSymbolizer sym = sf.getDefaultRasterSymbolizer();
 Style style = SLD.wrapSymbolizers(sym);
 Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
 StyleLayer stLayer = (StyleLayer) layer;
 stLayer.setStyle(style);
 mapContent.addLayer(stLayer);


I would assume a raster layer is a coverage not a featureSource - you'll need the gt-postgis-raster module

Do I have to create a XML file like: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/unsupported/postgis-raster/README.md ?

I've never used it (I never saw the point of storing rasters in a database)

I was thinking of making a mosaic map from a lot of raster files to be able to cut out the areas I want as a new raster files.
